# How to prevent double reflectioln on plexiglass/acrylic material?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

I have a light source that will reflect readable information off of a piece of Plexiglas. As the question suggests, how can I angle, shift, adjust, or alter my light/Plexiglas to prevent the double reflection caused by the distance between the two sides of the Plexiglas so the viewer can more clearly view the data provided?

Here's a picture that illustrates my problem:[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place a polarizing filter over the LED display, and if your glass is tilted at about 57 degrees relative to the direction from the display to the viewer's eyes, then there will be almost no reflection from the glass surfaces.  That angle is known as [Brewster's angle](https://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/java/polarizedlight/brewster/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologize for not making my question clear initially, but I am looking for a way to eliminate the second reflection from the Plexiglas while keeping the first one. The goal is for the viewer to see the information projected by the OLED display as shown in the picture. Thanks again!

Comment: Brewster's angle may still be the answer to your problem.  If one surface of the @microbob, Plexiglas has a reflective, semitransparent coating, and the light is polarized and incident at Brewster's angle, then there will be very little if any reflection from the second surface.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I angle, shift, adjust, or alter my light/Plexiglas to prevent the double reflection caused by the distance between the two sides of the Plexiglas?

Alter the angle of the light so the reflection doesn't hit your eyes.

[image: Angle of light determines the angle of reflection]

Light from the side, not from behind you. Other materials, such as glass, have reduced or no double reflection; but you asked specifically about acrylic (Plexiglass™). Plexiglass and other transparent materials can be sputtered with an anti-reflective coating to almost eliminate reflections. Museums have this figured out, they sometimes use [TruView](https://tru-vue.com/2017/11/interactions-between-museum-lighting-and-optically-coated-glazing/) acrylic sheets.

Thin-film coatings can be applied to glazing materials to provide a range of characteristics. The most immediately obvious of which is to reduce reflections. TruVue uses sputter coating to physically and chemically bond layers of metal oxides to glazing materials, which reduce reflections by creating optical interference. With these coatings reflection can be reduced to 1% or less. In turn, visible light transmission through the glazing will be increased to 98% or more.

Aesthetic appreciation of an artwork will be improved by both the removal of distracting reflections and by allowing more visible light to fall on the work, potentially allowing for greater clarity of fine detail and a more realistic interpretation of the colours.

[image: The problem caused by reflection from two surfaces]

When light, travelling as a wave, falls on a piece of glazing, three things will happen. Some will be reflected, some will be absorbed by the glazing material, and some will travel through. Reflections can be reduced by using several layers of thin-film coatings to create optical interference. By managing the reflections off each layer of material, the reflected light waves can cancel each other out.

Since visible light will be travelling in a variety of wavelengths, reducing the overall reflection is a delicate balance based upon the refractive index of the material used for each coating layer, its thickness, and its position within the coating stack. Any residual reflections seen in optically coated glazing will have a colour to them. This colour will depend upon the type of light source, its colour temperature, and the type or brand of glazing material used.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologize for not making my question clear initially, but I am looking for a way to eliminate the second reflection from the Plexiglas while keeping the first one. The goal is for the viewer to see the information projected by the OLED display as shown in the picture. Thanks again!

Comment: @Microbob - "... viewer to see the information **projected** by the OLED display as shown in the picture." - So this is from a projector?, and you wish to be able to see the reflection while on the same side as the projector ... -- Same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Anti-reflection coatings. You cannot make it yourself (thickness 1/4 wavelength) but acrylic panes with such coatings are commercially available. Google "antireflection coating acrylic".

Answer (score 0):

You can immerse the LED display in mineral oil ($n \sim 1.5$) or something with similar index of refraction to that of the plexiglas ($n \sim 1.5$).

Thinner plexiglas would help too.